# AWS Quicksight calculated field average

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, kpi

Hi I am having trouble with this calculated field. I am trying to get the sum of money_val for each customerkey. Then I want to have a KPI visual to show the average money_val. I found that PRE_AGG and PRE_FILTER gave wrong values so I want to use POST_AGG_FILTER.

```
sumOver(sum({money_val}),[customerkey], POST_AGG_FILTER)
```

But when I put it in the value field well of the KPI visual, I get this:

[image]

I only have cust-amnt-total(custom) as a Value in the field well. Also, how can I get the average since the only option is Custom?

Comment: "_A KPI displays a value comparison, the two values being compared, and a progress bar._" while `sumOver` should return multiple rows. Are you sure that KPI is a correct visualization for your data?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to have money_val and customerkey in your field wells for the visual to work, but I am unsure what you are trying to achieve here