# Quicksight aggregations on a field

Tags: dashboard, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Hi I am having trouble with this calculated field. I am trying to get the sum of money_val for each customerkey. Then I want to have a KPI visual to show the average money_val. I found that PRE_AGG and PRE_FILTER gave wrong values so I want to use POST_AGG_FILTER.

sumOver(sum({money_val}),[customerkey], POST_AGG_FILTER)
But when I put it in the value field well of the KPI visual, I get this:

enter image description here

I only have cust-amnt-total(custom) as a Value in the field well. Also, how can I get the average since the only option is Custom?

Comment: Is there a reason for having exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437253/aws-quicksight-calculated-field-average) one but without image?

Comment: @GuruStron No we are both working on this project so we posted it together to find a solution.